# how to use ajax and php to develop a three step wizard on the same page

Tags: php, ajax, wizard

I try to implement a 3step wizard on the same page with ajax. I use two php files to create Form2 and Form3. It is no problem with the first step to create Form2. But I got stuck with the second step to create Form3. 
I have changed the validation code of Form2 according to the suggestion below and here is the new code. The data returned from the createForm3.php are correct but cannot be shown at div id="form3".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form1").validate({ ...
      alert("I am in form1 validation");
      submitHandler: function(form) {   
              $.post('createForm2.php', $("#form1").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#form2').html(data); 
                    $("#form2").validate({ ...
                    alert("I am in form2 validation");
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $.post('createForm3.php', $("#form2").serialize(), function(data) {
                       alert(data);
               $('#form3').html(data);  });}});
   });}});      

});
</script>
<body>
<form name = 'form1' id = 'form1' action = '' method = 'POST'>
....
<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'Submit'>
</form>
<div id="form2"><div>
<div id="form3"><div>
</body>
```

In createForm3.php for testing:   echo " Show form 3 ";

Comment: saw the alert(data) but nothing was shown in the form3 div

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you probably need to move your `#form2` validation event handler to the success function of the `#form1` submit handler.

Now, when you attach your event handler to `#form2`, there is no form yet in that element as that gets created using ajax so anything you try to attach to it will fail.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the validation code of Form2 according to the suggestion below and here is the new code. The data returned from the createForm3.php are correct but cannot be shown at div id="form3".

Answer (score 0):

You are activating the validate function on form2 while it is still doesn't exist, so the validation method is never called on form2.

What you need to do is call the form validation on form2 in the ajax callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form1").validate({ ...
      submitHandler: function(form) {   
              $.post('createForm2.php', $("#form1").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#form2').html(data); 
     $("#form2").validate({ ...})

   });}});


    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the validation code of Form2 according to the suggestion below and here is the new code. The data returned from the createForm3.php are correct but cannot be shown at div id="form3".

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is form2 working now? Do you see the alert(data) of form3?

Comment: Yes, saw the alert(data) but nothing was shown in the form3 div even the createForm3.php is just an echo for testing purpose.

Comment: So let me get it straight, when you do alert(data) you see 'Show form 3' but it does not appear in the div?

Comment: Hi, Ftom2, exactly. can see show form 3 but not appear in div. Any idea or suggest I can try?